# Call .bat file from anywhere in the directory using python

Tags: file, python-2.7, batch-file, directory, call

I need to call a .bat file from anywhere in the directory without including the specific directory in the script. You'll just need to specify the name of .bat file you want to call and then run. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add the .bat file's directory into your PATH.

This is an article for you.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

do you mean calling a script without specifying the exact location from commandline?

there are two ways:

1. add it to your path (eg: set it in your PATH environment variable)
2. setup an alias/some sort of shortcut in your bashrc/whatever CLI you are using (since you are using windows, one example would be to setup a cmdlet in windows powershell or something)

Comment: I mean calling the bat file without specifying the exact location from the python script not from the command line.

Comment: you could try to do `os.chdir`

Comment: or specify the bat file location somewhere (eg: in a settings file etc) and load those settings in when u run the python script

Comment: Can you give me an example(using chdir) in python script?

Comment: what? confused what you mean

Comment: Example of how to use chdir as you suggested. Let's say I want to call sample.bat from anywhere in the directory without specifying the location of the sample file? Because I don't want to specify any location. I just want to call the file I need to run.

Comment: I am assuming you don't want to specify the location as a matter of convenience right? So just put `import os; os.chdir('bashscriptlocation')` in the beginning of the script

Comment: So you mean I need to add the path first before running the 'os.chdir', am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64284/discussion-between-conrad-and-user).